# Close Button out of place on Dialog box Jquery UI, ASP MVC4 .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

i made  a simple dialog box to display some text, it works fine, but the cross mark(close button) its out of position, i have not been able to fix this and i already searched all google to figure it out.

this is how it looks:

[image]

here is the code of the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Exito";
}


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="message" title="Exito">
  <p>La cantidad de caracteres en la oracion es de: </p><div id="target" ></div><p> <b>(Incluyendo el "hola, escribiste:")</b></p>
</div>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hola, Escribiste: ";
}



<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#message').dialog({


        resizable: false
    });

</script>

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <h2 id="userMessage">@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>




<script type="text/javascript">
    var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: " + $('#userMessage').html();
    var myLength = Texto.length;
   // document.write("La cantidad de caracteres en la oracion es de " + myLength + " (Incluyendo el 'hola, escribiste')");
    $("#target").text(myLength);
   </script>
```

Comment: simplest thing to do is inspect the element in browser console and see what CSS rules are affecting it. You can even do live edits in the console to see what fixes it

Comment: in the console it gives me these <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Close</span></button>

Comment: that's the html, now look at the CSS rules that apply to that element, can see them (in the console) for any element in the DOM

Comment: Please put your div tag code using firebug that you get in browse.

Comment: @Aravindan and what good will that do. It's the same as any other dialog except something in the CSS is conflicting

Comment: It will shows you if some unwanted class add to the div at runtime.